# Modifying JQuery Live Filtering Solution to Filter on Multiple Attribute Values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've been building a live filtering solution out of an existing third-party product using XHTML, CSS, and JS. I was able to get phase 1 to work, but I guess the 'award' for solving problems is new and bigger problems to solve. Hooray! :D  So, here's the sitch...

I have three Select Multiple dropdown menus that filter the divs on a page based on corresponding menu values. Users were able to select multiple options in each menu to filter objects on the page. For example:

HTML Menus

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="product" class="filterby">                           
   <option value="Product1">
    Product 1
   </option>
   <option value="Product2">
    Product 2
   </option>
   <option value="Product3">
    Product 3
   </option>
</select>

<select multiple="multiple" id="role" class="filterby">                           
   <option value="Tech">
    Technician
   </option>
   <option value="Manager">
    Manager
   </option>
   <option value="ITS">
    IT Specialist
   </option>
</select>

<select multiple="multiple" id="type" class="filterby">                           
   <option value="HDesk">
    Help Desk Request
   </option>
   <option value="ServCent">
    Service Center Call
   </option>
   <option value="Onsite">
    Onsite Visit
   </option>
</select>
```

Originally, divs on the page included corresponding menu values, allowing the solution to filter the content appropriately, like so:

```
<div class="Product1 Product3 Manager Onsite"> Paragraphs, images, videos and other neat stuff in my div </div>
```

In the above example, this div would appear for users if they selected one or multiple matching menu options. Pretty basic, right?

And the JQuery that supported this was just ELEGANT! I found it on StackOverflow and I LOVE it. Worked great!!!

```
    $("select.filterby").change(function(){
    var filters = $.map($("select.filterby").toArray(), function(e){
        return $(e).val();
    }).join(".");
    $("div#FilterContainer").find("div").hide();
    $("div#FilterContainer").find("div." + filters).show();
});
```

These few lines of code mapped and joined any selected items from ALL THREE of my multiselect menus and 'showed/hid' divs appropriately. A thing of beauty. So mighty!

OK.  Now that I've had success with this, there are new requirements (of course):

- I need my code to find paragraphs instead of divs.
- I need my code to match my menu values with paragraph attribute values instead of classes that used to contain values for filtering.
- I need my code to show or hide paragraphs like it did before based on one or many menu selections.

I have tried many methods to get this to go, none of which seem to work.

Here is where I've gotten thus far:

```
    $("select.filterby").change(function(){
    var filters = $.map($("select.filterby").toArray(), function(e){
        return $(e).val();
    }).join(".");
    $("p[data-mc-conditions]").hide();
    $("p[data-mc-conditions]"+ filters).show();
});
```

This will NOT work, because all of the paragraphs on the page now contain the 'data-mc-conditons' attribute. Example:

```
<p data-mc-conditions="Default.Product1,Default.Product3,Default.Manager,Default.Onsite>Content"</p>
```

So, simply defining the attribute 'data-mc-conditions' doesn't take me far enough. I have to specify the attribute value as well, which would be something like:

```
"p[data-mc-conditions='Default.Product1']"
```

But that's REALLY specific and doesn't seem to work anyway. I would have to create entries for each attribute value pair. Not great.

So, here's the original JQuery again for your convenience:

```
    $("select.filterby").change(function(){
    var filters = $.map($("select.filterby").toArray(), function(e){
        return $(e).val();
    }).join(".");
    $("div#FilterContainer").find("div").hide();
    $("div#FilterContainer").find("div." + filters).show();
});
```

What I would need is:

```
    $("select.filterby").change(function(){
    var filters = $.map($("select.filterby").toArray(), function(e){
        return $(e).val();
    }).join(".");

   // If data-mc-condition values DON'T match selected menu values, hide <p>
   // If data-mc-condition values DO match selected menu values, show <p>
    
});
```

Or any equivalent if the above code no longer supports what I'm attempting to do.
I really appreciate your help! <3

Comment: Please provide a runnable code snippet with enough HTML, css, and JS so that could submit the working answer.

Comment: what are the values that data-mc-conditions may contain

Comment: `[data-mc-conditions='Default.Product1']` would only select an element, where the data attribute has _exactly_ that value. `[attr~=value]` would work if you had a whitespace-separated list of "words" as the attribute content, but that is not the case here, you got them comma-separated. So you could really only use `[attr*=value]` here - _"represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value contains at least one occurrence of value within the string."_ (MDN)

Comment: @CBroe Thanks so much! I'm still learning what's valid syntax-wise. Can you reply with the correct syntax to include [attr*=value] within the following? Many thanks!!!

Comment: $("div#FilterContainer").find("div." + filters).show();

Comment: @VijayHardaha Hey! Thanks so much for being willing to take a look! I will post something better for you to work with.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you reply with the correct syntax to include [attr*=value] within the following?

To figure out which parts we need to stick together how, let's write the result we actually want, for multiple selected values:

```
[attr*='value'][attr*='value'][attr*='value']
```

The `value` parts are the dynamic ones we will get from our array, the rest we need to add - and with this, it is easy to determine what we need to put between the values (via `.join()`), and which parts need to be appended before and after:

```
[attr*='value'][attr*='value'][attr*='value']
^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^     ^^
before       between        between        after
```

Now here your actual attribute name is `data-mc-conditions`, and we need to add `Default.` before each value, so we can use this

```
$("select.filterby").change(function() {
  var filters = "[data-mc-conditions*='Default." +
     $.map($("select.filterby").toArray(), function(e) {
       return $(e).val();
     }).join("'][data-mc-conditions*='Default.") + 
     "']";
  console.log(filters)
});
```

This will get us a result such as

```
[data-mc-conditions*='Default.Product2'][data-mc-conditions*='Default.Product3'][data-mc-conditions*='Default.Manager']
```

And now that can be inserted to generate the full selector for the elements we still want to see after hiding all of them:

```
$("div#FilterContainer p" + filters).show();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a5q4cw2x/